# Why is my help command not working? i dont se anythin wrong with it

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm using discord.py rewrite and in my help.py folder where I have my help command when I hover over the help command it says `"help" is not accessedPylance (function) help: (ctx) -> None` 
I'm using vscode
here is my help command code if you need

`````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        @commands.command(aliases=["commands"])
        async def help(ctx,):
            embed = discord.Embed(title = "What TimmyBot can do", description = "All the Commands TimmyBot can do so far", color = discord.Colour.light_grey())
            embed.add_field(name = "````~Fun~````", value="**mindfuck** - A wholesome mindfuck :open_mouth: \n **deez** - Got em :peanuts: \n **fact** - Shows you a fact you may know or may not :nerd: \n **kill** - kills a user :dizzy_face: \n **avatar** - shows the avatar of the person you chose",inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="```~Utilities~```", value="**stats** - shows timmybot's latency and version :bar_chart: \n **user** - shows the information of the user that u @mentioned :detective:", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="```~Moderation~```", value="**kick** - kicks a player :wave: \n **ban** - bans a player :exclamation: \n **unban** - unbans a player :white_check_mark: \n **clear** - clears messages (default 1) :dizzy_face:", inline = False)
            embed.set_footer(text="Developed by YaBoiPerry#0326", icon_url='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/LO8P_gAGXzJmS-vKWN1XAnzjg7oHOeI26yHI7BtFAL8oSzI-T5EMVH6_TC39FoxHe-LoIA=s120')
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(help(bot))
`````

Answer (score 0):

Well your code looks fine except for 1 thing

help is already a builtin

```py
>>> type(help)
<class '_sitebuiltins._Helper'>
```

so python gets confused when you use the same name for a class and a builtin

renaming the "helps" in the code should fix it

Answer (score 0):

In discord.py, a built-in `help` command has already existed on the bot, so you can just remove it by doing it on the main file.

In Main.py, put:

`client.remove_command("help")`

This way it will remove the default help command.

And lastly, you didn't put `self` on the parenthesis. you just put (ctx, ) there. In cog, every command must put `self` on the parenthesis.

Here is the updated code :

`````py
        @commands.command(aliases=["commands"])
        async def help(self, ctx): # added self on the parenthesis
            embed = discord.Embed(title = "What TimmyBot can do", description = "All the Commands TimmyBot can do so far", color = discord.Colour.light_grey())
            embed.add_field(name = "````~Fun~````", value="**mindfuck** - A wholesome mindfuck :open_mouth: \n **deez** - Got em :peanuts: \n **fact** - Shows you a fact you may know or may not :nerd: \n **kill** - kills a user :dizzy_face: \n **avatar** - shows the avatar of the person you chose",inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="```~Utilities~```", value="**stats** - shows timmybot's latency and version :bar_chart: \n **user** - shows the information of the user that u @mentioned :detective:", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="```~Moderation~```", value="**kick** - kicks a player :wave: \n **ban** - bans a player :exclamation: \n **unban** - unbans a player :white_check_mark: \n **clear** - clears messages (default 1) :dizzy_face:", inline = False)
            embed.set_footer(text="Developed by YaBoiPerry#0326", icon_url='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/LO8P_gAGXzJmS-vKWN1XAnzjg7oHOeI26yHI7BtFAL8oSzI-T5EMVH6_TC39FoxHe-LoIA=s120')
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
`````

thank me later :D